# RDS のストレージサイズを小さくしたい

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

現在 MySQL の DB インスタンスがあり、100GB のストレージを割り当てています。
使用率は1％以下で、無駄に多く料金を支払っていると感じています。
ストレージサイズを 5GB まで小さくするにはどうしたらいいでしょうか。

- エンジン: mysql 5.6.19b
- クラス: db.m1.small
- ストレージ: Magnetic 100GB
- シングルAZ
- Publicly accessible: No

Answer (score 4, accepted):

・容量が小さなRDSインスタンスを作成
・現在のRDSインスタンスからmysqldumpでエクスポート
・新しいRDSインスタンスにインポート
で行うことができます。

また、追加で下記の手順を実施することで、新旧のインスタンスのIdentifierを同じにすることができます。

・現在のRDSインスタンスのIdentifierを変更 (Ex: mydb -> mydb-old)
・新しいRDSインスタンスのIdentifierを現在のRDSのものに変更 (Ex: mydb-new -> mydb)
・不要になったRDSインスタンスを削除

Comment: ありがとうございます。作りの直してストレージをリサイズできました。新旧のRDSインスタンスのIdentifierを同じ内容にしたかったので回答に追記させてもらいました。

Answer (score 0):

以下の手順で設定できるかと思います。
①RDSダッシュボードのInstances画面にて、DBインスタンスを右クリック
②メニューから「Modify」を選択
③「Allocated Storage」という項目を5に設定する
④すぐに適用したい場合は「Apply Immediately」にチェックを入れる
⑤「Continue」ボタンを押す
⑥「Modify DB Instance」ボタンを押す

Comment: 残念ながら「Allocated Storage cannot be reduced」と表示され変更出来ませんでした。

Comment: @take88
あ。。公式のドキュメントによると、ストレージを増やすことはできるけど、減らすことはできないとのことでした。。
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ModifyInstance.MySQL.html